# Is it possible customize user login page on Adaptive Theme?

Tags: 7, users, theming

I tried many solutions for change my mysite.com/user page. I want, only login-register-forgotten form is visible, other block hidden. But what i try a solution, don't working.

Is it possible? How can i do this?

This is my past question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65475/error-when-creating-a-custom-page-in-d7

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to hide blocks, go to the block configuration page (/admin/structure/block), celect 'configure' for the blocks you wish to hide, and under 'Block Visibility Settings' on the 'Page' tab select 'All pages except those listed '. Then if your login url is '/user/login', enter 'user/login' in the box. If you enter 'user/*' it will exclude the block from all pages matching the pattern.